# Hibernate is generating the same foreign key constraint multiple times with inheritance strategy SINGLE_TABLE

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I am modelling two types of variables, call them `AVar`, and `BVar`. They each can be associated with multiple values, of type `AValue`, and `BValue` respectively. I decided to use inheritance, so that each concrete class inherits from an abstract base class (Variable or Value).

I then have a ManyToOne mapping from the abstract Value to abstract Variable. For Variable I am using `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance. For Value, I am using `TABLE_PER_CLASS` inheritance. Hibernate supports all this and generates the tables fine, however, I get the same foreign key constraint 3 times, which is doubly redundant. Is there something wrong with my set up, or is this a Hibernate bug?

Output from Hibernate schema update:

```
HHH000262: Table not found: dm_variables
HHH000262: Table not found: dm_variables_a_values
HHH000262: Table not found: dm_variables_b_values

create table dm_variables (type varchar(31) not null, id varchar(36) not null, version bigint not null, name varchar(255) not null, variable_set_id varchar(36) not null, primary key (id), unique (variable_set_id, name))
create table dm_variables_a_values (id varchar(36) not null, version bigint not null, [current] bit not null, variable_id varchar(36) not null, member_id int, primary key (id))
create table dm_variables_b_values (id varchar(36) not null, version bigint not null, [current] bit not null, variable_id varchar(36) not null, string_value varchar(255), primary key (id))

alter table dm_variables_a_values add constraint FK__dm_values__variable_id90d2dd34 foreign key (variable_id) references dm_variables
alter table dm_variables_a_values add constraint FK7ED02C351F5CFA0E90d2dd34 foreign key (variable_id) references dm_variables
alter table dm_variables_a_values add constraint FK7ED02C35F9E9BFC090d2dd34 foreign key (variable_id) references dm_variables
alter table dm_variables_b_values add constraint FK__dm_values__variable_id5135dfd4 foreign key (variable_id) references dm_variables
alter table dm_variables_b_values add constraint FK7ED02C351F5CFA0E5135dfd4 foreign key (variable_id) references dm_variables
alter table dm_variables_b_values add constraint FK7ED02C35F9E9BFC05135dfd4 foreign key (variable_id) references dm_variables

HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

Code (simplified):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dm_variables")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Variable extends BaseEntity {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "A")
public class AVar extends Variable {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "B")
public class BVar extends Variable {
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Value extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "variable_id", nullable = false)
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK__dm_values__variable_id")
    private Variable variable;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "dm_variables_a_values")
public class ValueA extends Value {
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "dm_variables_b_values")
public class ValueB extends Value {
}
```

Comment: after schema update, how many constraints do you have in dm_variables_a_values ?

Comment: I get 3 constraints saying the same thing. "foreign key (variable_id) references dm_variables". You can see this in Hibernate's output which is in the original question.

Comment: what you post is the schema update script, I was just wondering if the 3 constraints were created AFTER script execution.

Comment: what message do you have when try to insert a row violating the contraint ? (you must have a ConstraintViolationException, but what is the constraint name displayed in the exception message ?)

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes, all 6 constraints were created. This is in SQL Server, which I guess allows redundant constraints like that. The message I get is "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__dm_values__variable_id90d2dd34". The conflict occurred in database "<db_name>", table "dbo.dm_variables", column 'id'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is really a bug. I agree that it is not optimal, but this behavior don't have too much consequences. In particular :

- the constraint violation error message contains the constraint name you have specified with the @Constraint
- we can expect that, at runtime, constraints are evaluated in sequence and as soon as one constraint is violated the other aren't evaluated.

Additionally, the shema-update feature is not a core feature of the framework (even if it is widely used and powerful) and I don't think that this behavior is breaking the *schema-update* contract. In my opinion, it can be a minor improvement.

Comment: I eventually found that this relationship was not quite accurate for my specific business case. Revising it removed this behaviour. You are right that it is harmless, however, I still think it is a bug. :)